# Trying to query select cells based on data in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Not really sure what’s wrong with my function but I’ve tried so many different variations to make it work and I keep getting an `#ERROR!` with a “formula parse error” pop-up

What I’m trying to do is populate a sheet from data in another sheet. I only want specific cells in Column C from the other sheet to populate based on the text contained in Column D cells (on the ‘other’ sheet)

So the fxn i have going now is:
`=QUERY({‘[insert other sheet name]’!C3:D}; “select C where D=“‘[insert desired text]’;0)`

I’ve tried the fxn without the ‘C where D ...’ part and it worked fine populating all of the data without selecting any specific cells so I’m sure that’s where the problem is.
I’ve also tried `”select C where D contains ‘[insert desired text]’”` or `”select C where D = ‘[insert desired text]’”` and a number of other variations with no luck ... anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't use** these `”` , `‘` or `’`.

Instead **do use** these `"` or `'`.

Try this:

`=QUERY('insert other sheet name'!C3:D; "select C where D contains 'insert desired text' ";0)`

or this:

`=QUERY('insert other sheet name'!C3:D; "select C where D = 'insert desired text' ";0)`

Comment: Omg that worked!! 0.0 Thanks so much!! I was about to start smacking my head into a wall lol